# Improve AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer performance when capturing in photo quality

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, preview, avcapturesession

I am working on augmented reality app, the main feature of which is to show the overlay over the camera preview, but I also need to be able to save the high resolution photo with the overlay applied. 
For this purpose I set up the `AVCaptureSession` with preset set to `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`. But the smoothness and responsiveness of AVPreviewLayer for such session is much worse then for preset `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh`. At the same time the area which is shown in preview with `AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh` preset is smaller than with `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`. But that is not that important for me.

So the question is how to capture the photo in high quality from the camera, but have the same  level of responsiveness of previewLayer as in case of video capture?

Comment: I would use preset high for the preview. When taking a photo I would project the overlay into the dimensions for the photo adjusting for any aspect ratio changes. If the aspect ratio is the same then I do believe this would just be a scaling operation on the overlay image(s).

Comment: Yes, I think that is the only way of doing this, which is quite suitable. Thanks for the answer.